# Angular 10 model with variable sub-models?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm describing a list with a model, but the list can contain either of two different data structures (also defined as models). Is there a way to declare this kind of structure?

```
import { AssetFull } from './asset.model'
import { AssetLink } from './asset.model'

export class Roster {
  public title: string;
  public manifest: string;
  public assets: {
    quantity: number,
    asset: AssetFull // OR AssetLink
  }[];
}
```

Would I just make the asset type `any`?

Comment: Just `asset: AssetFull | AssetLink`

Comment: You can also define as ->  asset: any